# unable to access instance variable in different method in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In search() method I am setting value to `ss` variable, but getting `null` when when trying to access this inside run() or any other method.

Recently I came to spring from struts. This senerio is possible in struts but i dont know why its not taking in spring.

**Note** I can't use here `static` keyword because its a multi user application.

```
@Controller
public class AddEmployee implements Runnable {
// instance variable having getter() and setter() method.
    String ss;

    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public String search(Model model, @RequestParam String text) throws InterruptedException {
        setSs(text); // setting value in ss
        AddEmployee r = new AddEmployee();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return "listEmployee";
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$--->"+getSs());// getting null here
    }

    public String getSs() {
        return ss;
    }

    public void setSs(String ss) {
        this.ss = ss;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that  the `text` variable is not null ?

Comment: @BOUALIALI Yes I am sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `ss` on `this`, but your runnable is a `new AddEmployee()` So you have two instances of your controller: one created by Spring, having the `ss` field set, and another one, created by you, which doesn't have its `ss` set.

Your Runnable instance shouldn't be an instance of the controller. Use another, different class, and pass the text as an argument to the constructor of this class:

```
public String search(Model model, @RequestParam String text) throws InterruptedException {
    MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(text);
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    return "listEmployee";
}
```

Also, remember that a controller is a singleton: Spring creates a single instance of each controller. Storing request-scoped data in a field of a controller is as wrong as storing it in a static variable.